# Flex Mobile Animation Using left property

Tags: apache-flex, animation, mobile

I need helping in creating a simple animation for my app that moves an image left from where it's current position is, for a given distance, say a user decided to move it a given distance through a textfield or something similar. Simply put, I have no way of telling where the image will be placed when it needs to be moved but it needs to move left for a distance that I guess I'll be able to define once I get it moving left.

Any assitance you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GreenSock Animation Platform](http://www.greensock.com/v12/).  You'll want to make sure that your image is placed in a container with a `BasicLayout`.

Then all you have to do is:

```
var newX:int = myObject.x - parseInt(myTextArea.text);
var duration:int = 1; //1 second
TweenLite.to(myObject, duration, {x:newX});
```